# What is the point of completing a Boolean algebra?

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be the Cantor space $2^\omega$ and $Clop(X)$ be the field of open-closed subsets of $X$. It is known that $Clop(X)$ is incomplete, and a minimal completion of $Clop(X)$ is e.g. the regular open algebra $RO(X)$ of $X$.

$Clop(X)$ embeds naturally into $RO(X)$ because every open-closed set is regular open. So what really matters for the completion is the case involving infinite operations. But what is the point of even considering such infinite operations if they are not defined in $Clop(X)$ in the first place?

It is a question that eludes me. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a really strange question.  What's the point of completing $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ so you can consider limits, if those limits are not defined in $\mathbb{Q}$ in the first place?

Comment: Two separative partial orders can have entirely different properties, but have the same Boolean completion. That, on its own, is a good enough reason to complete Boolean algebras.

Comment: Well, yes @Eric, this my point too, unless you consider sigma-algebras, which is what David does below. But, RO(X) is not a minimal completion of the sigma-algebra generated by Clop(X).

Answer (score 2):

One interesting application of the notion of a complete Boolean algebra is this: *measure algebras are complete*. Hmm, you wanted to know what good is completeness; this is just an interesting instance of completeness. Look at it this way:: What's below is an interesting and not at all trivial fact about measure theory, and the proof is an application of the completeness of the lattice of orthogonal projections on a Hilbert space.

Or: The interesting fact about measure theory is an application of, in fact is equivalent to, the completeness of the algebra of clopen subsets of the maximal ideal space of $L^\infty$.

Anyway, ($\sigma$-finite) measure spaces are complete. In other words: Say $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space; in particular $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Now $\Sigma$ is not closed under arbitrary unions, but an arbitrary subset of $\Sigma$ *does* have a least upper bound modulo null sets, in this sense:

> > Suppose $(E_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ is a collection of measurable sets. There exists $E\in\Sigma$ such that for every $\alpha\in A$ we have $\mu(E_\alpha\setminus E)=0$, and if $E'$ is another set with this property then $\mu(E\setminus E')=0$.

That is, $E$ almost contains every $E_\alpha$, and any other measurable set that almost contains every $E_\alpha$ almost contains $E$; so in a sense $E$ is almost the union of the $E_\alpha$.

Sketch of proof if $\mu(X)<\infty$ (the $\sigma$-finite case follows easily):

Say $V_\alpha$ is the subspace of $L^2(\mu)$ consisting of the functions that vanish almost everywhere on $X\setminus E_\alpha$. Let $V$ be the closed span of the $V_\alpha$ in $L^2$.

It's easy to verify that if $f\in V$ and $\phi\in L^\infty$ then $\phi f\in V$. It's not hard to show from this that if $P:L^2\to V$ is the orthogonal projection then $P(\phi f)=\phi P(f)$ for $f\in L^2$ and $\phi\in L^\infty$.

Now $L^2\subset L^1$, so $f\mapsto\int Pf$ defines a bounded linear functional on $L^2$; hence there exists $m\in L^2$ such that $$\int Pf=\int mf\quad(f\in L^2).$$If $\phi\in L^\infty$ and $f\in L^2$ then $\int\phi Pf=\int P(\phi f)=\int\phi mf;$ since $Pf,mf\in L^1$ this shows that $$Pf=mf\quad(f\in L^2).$$(Not that we need to say this at this point, but in particular  $||mf||_2\le||f||_2$ for all $f\in L^2$, hence $||m||_\infty\le 1$.) Since $P^2=P$ we must have $m^2=m$, so there exists $E$ with $m=\chi_E$; the result follows. (Show first that $V$ is the space of all $f\in L^2$ which vanish almost everywhere on $X\setminus E$.)

**Edit:** Actually I was bluffing somewhat there - recalled that you could do  this this way but didn't quite recall the punchline. The final  "the result follows" goes like so:

First, since $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $V$ and $V_\alpha\subset V$, we have $Pf=f$ for every $f\in V_\alpha$. In particular $\chi_E\chi_{E_\alpha}=\chi_{E_\alpha}$, so $\mu(E_\alpha\setminus E)=0$.

Now suppose that $\mu(E_\alpha\setminus E')=0$ for every $\alpha$. Then $\chi_{E'}f=f$ for every $f\in V_\alpha$, and hence for every $f\in V$. But $P\chi_E=\chi_E^2=\chi_E$, hence $\chi_E\in V$. So $\chi_{E'}\chi_E=\chi_E$, hence $\mu(E\setminus E')=0$.

Comment: Thank you @David for your reply. I notice, however, that you bring sigma-algebras into the picture. BTW, RO(X) is also isomorphic to the Borel sets modulo meagre sets, but no measure exists on it. So it seems that my question is still pending...

Comment: Well first, I wasn't trying to answer exactly your specific question, was trying just to give an example of why the completion of an algebra might be interesting. Second, huh??? "... modulo null sets" but there's no measure in the picture?

Comment: I rather had in mind the Borel sets mod meagre sets more than the Borel sets mod null sets. Thank you anyway for you reply, which is on its own sake interesting.

Comment: I think there is an easier proof that requires no functional analytic methods: Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the set of finite unions of sets in the family and let $\langle U_n\rangle$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{U}$ that converges to $\sup\{\mu(U)\mid U\in\mathcal{U}\}$. Then it is easy to verify that $\bigcup_n U_n$ is a minimum upper bound.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker It's immediately clear that there cannot be a smaller upper bound. Took me a minute to see why it _is_ an upper bound. But I believe you're right. Too bad, my version is more fun, heh...